# How can I put an image on the left of a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a application with a listbox of contacts. I wonderd if there is any current and easy way of getting the users profile image on the left of the listBox just before the text for the same size?

And the image to be square before every item's text

Comment: Any reason not to use a ListView instead ?

Comment: I dont know what that is never mind how to create one. Could you give me some advice on that suggestion?

Comment: Please include some code with your question so that we can try and help.

Comment: I have not tried any code because I don't know how to do it. Thats why i asked for some help

Comment: It might be a good idea to have a look through the Toolbox to see what controls are available to you.  Don't ignore information that is right at your fingertips.  The ListView is just another control and you create one the same way you create a ListBox or any other control.  It's a bit more complex than a ListBox but displaying an image for each item is going to be more complex in a ListBox than a ListView.  Maybe you should do a bit of reading on the ListView.  If you have problems, ask a new question and we can help with that.

Comment: By the way, the right-hand side of Windows Explorer uses a ListView, so you get an idea of what it can do, including showing an image for each item.